# Using a Twitter Bootstrap media query to set a Razor view variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my Razor view I have the following code to layout the page. However based on the media query I want to change the value of numberOfColumns. So that when MD I use 2 and when SM I use 1 - ie. Change how many columns I output based on the media query. Is this possible?

If not is there another way to do this?

```
bool inRow = false;
int numberOfColumns = 3;    //<---- Change based on media query
int columnNumber = 0;
foreach (OzCpCruiseListItem cruiseItem in Model.CruisesBrief)
{
    columnNumber++;
    if (columnNumber == 1)
    {
        inRow = true;
    }

    if (inRow && columnNumber == 1)
    {
        @Html.Raw("<!-- START Row --><br />")
        @Html.Raw("<div class=\"row\">")
    }

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">    //<--- 3 col for large, 2 for medium, 1 small
    </div>

    if (columnNumber == numberOfColumns)
    {
        inRow = false;
        @Html.Raw("</div>")
        @Html.Raw("<!-- END Row --><br />")
        columnNumber = 0;
    }
}

//Close row if needed
if (inRow)
{
    @Html.Raw("<!-- END AT END Row --><br />")
    @Html.Raw("</div")
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. You are already choosing the number of columns by picking the right `col-*` classes.

Comment: @DavidG Yes but based on my loop I am currently always putting out 3 columns all the time no matter the view port size. As the view port size changes I need to vary that to either 1 or 2 columns. So does that mean I have to output the data 3 times one for each media query?

Comment: No, just loop around your collection and put them inside the div you have.

Comment: Yes but it I do that then for instance because I have 3 columns then when it goes to md-6 I get two cells and then the 3rd cell is the next row down.

Comment: Well you did say you want 2 columns at md size.

Comment: So to achieve what I want is to output the content 3 times and then use the hidden-* classes to show / hide based on viewport I guess?

Comment: OK, you're really not making sense now. Why would you want to hide anything?

Comment: Let me re-state. When LG use 3 columns. When MD use 2 columns. When SM use 1 column. The only way I see to do that is to have 3 containing div's one for LG, MD, SM and then use the appropriate bootstrap class visible-* on each so that the rows don't partially wrap. Hopefully I am clearer?

Comment: When you say "3 columns", you mean 3 items in total? Usually that means three items per row with multiple rows.

Comment: 3 columns per row without the row wrapping. Currently when the viewport gets too narrow the 3rd column drops to the next line.

Comment: So what do you want to see when you have 10 items?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DavidG who tried to understand what I was on about. Below is my solution to what I was trying to ask for. Stated another way: "I never wanted the columns in the row to wrap to the next line when in a particular media query."

The only way I can come up to do this is to output some HTML per media query and vary the classes (for the columns) based on the number of columns I am expecting via:

```
result += $"<div class=\"col-{aMediaValue.ToLower()}-{columnSize}\">";
```

If there is a better way I would like to hear it as I don't like the fact I am outputting 4 lots of HTML for the same data - 1 for each media query.

```
@functions {
    HtmlString CardViewOutput(string aMediaValue)
    {
        string result = "";
        int columnCount;

        switch (aMediaValue.Trim().ToUpper())
        {
            case "LG":
                columnCount = 3;
                break;
            case "MD":
                columnCount = 2;
                break;
            case "SM":
            case "XS":
                columnCount = 1;
                break;
            default:
                columnCount = 1;
                break;
        }
        int columnSize = 12 / columnCount;


        bool inRow = false;
        int columnNumber = 0;
        foreach (OzCpCruiseListItem cruiseItem in Model.CruisesBrief)
        {
            columnNumber++;
            if (columnNumber == 1)
            {
                inRow = true;
            }

            if (inRow && columnNumber == 1)
            {
                result += "<!-- START Row --><br />";
                result += "<div class=\"row\">";
            }

            result += $"<div class=\"col-{aMediaValue.ToLower()}-{columnSize}\">";
            result += "</div>";


            if (columnNumber == columnCount)
            {
                inRow = false;
                result += "</div>";
                result += "<!-- END Row --><br />";
                columnNumber = 0;
            }
        }

        //Close row if needed
        if (inRow)
        {
            result += "<!-- END AT END Row --><br />";
            result += "</div>";
        }

        return new HtmlString(result);
    }
}

@*-- Card View -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*@
@if (Model.CruisesBrief.Count == 0)
{
    @Html.Raw("<div class=\"row\"><div class=\"col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12\">No cruises to display.</div></div>")
}
else
{
    @Html.Raw("<div class=\"visible-lg\">")
    @Html.Raw("LARGE")
    @Html.Raw(CardViewOutput("LG"))
    @Html.Raw("</div>")
    @Html.Raw("<div class=\"visible-md\">")
    @Html.Raw("MEDIUM")
    @Html.Raw(CardViewOutput("MD"))
    @Html.Raw("</div>")
    @Html.Raw("<div class=\"visible-sm\">")
    @Html.Raw("SMALL")
    @Html.Raw(CardViewOutput("SM"))
    @Html.Raw("</div>")
    @Html.Raw("<div class=\"visible-xs\">")
    @Html.Raw("EXTRA SMALL")
    @Html.Raw(CardViewOutput("XS"))
    @Html.Raw("</div>")
}
@*-- /Card View ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*@
```